# Error installing module l10n_es_aeat_mod303 from spanish odoo localization in odoo 9

Tags: localization, odoo, odoo-9

In odoo 9, installing the module l10n_es_aeat_mod303, from spanish localization, gives me this error:

```
(...)File "/etc/odoo/server/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_model.py", line 995, in xmlid_lookup
raise ValueError('External ID not found in the system: %s' % (xmlid))
ParseError: ""External ID not found in the system: l10n_es.account_tax_template_s_iva4b" while evaluating
"[(6, False, [ref('l10n_es.account_tax_template_s_iva4b'), ref('l10n_es.account_tax_template_s_iva4s')])]"" while parsing /etc/odoo/server/addons_extra/l10n_es_aeat_mod303/data/tax_code_map_mod303_data.xml:9, near
<record id="aeat_mod303_map_line_01" model="l10n.es.aeat.map.tax.line">
    <field name="map_parent_id" ref="aeat_mod303_map"/>
    <field name="field_number">01</field>
    <field name="name">R&#233;gimen General - Base imponible 4%</field>
    <field name="to_regularize" eval="False"/>
    <field name="move_type">regular</field>
    <field name="field_type">base</field>
    <field name="sum_type">both</field>
    <field name="inverse" eval="False"/>
<!-- Base facturas de venta (haber) - Descuentos en facturas de venta(debe):
     S_IVA4B, S_IVA4S -->
<field name="tax_ids" eval="[(6, False, [ref('l10n_es.account_tax_template_s_iva4b'), ref('l10n_es.account_tax_template_s_iva4s')])]"/>
```

It appears that it does not find the identifier "account_tax_template_s_iva4b". 

¿It is necessary to install some dependency before installing the module or how can I solve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that there is the official **l10n_es** module inside *addons* and another in *addons_extra*.

The main problem is that the conf file gives priority to the official addons, and then, the addons_extra:

```
addons_path = /odoo/addons,/odoo/addons_extra
```

To change this I followed these steps:

1. Make sure that the new module of **l10n_es** is inside addons_extra folder.
2. Put the path in the first place of *addons_path* parameter in conf file (the important part is that the official *addons path* will be after our new module path):

   `addons_path = /odoo/addons_extra/l10n-spain,/odoo/addons,/odoo/addons_extra`
3. Restart the server and update the module list.
4. Update the l10n_es module.

Now, the new module is installed and I can install the **l10n_es_aeat_mod303** module without errors.

Answer (score 1):

Issue is not related to **dependency**, but issue is in data.

In module **l10n_es_aeat_mod303**/**data/tax_code_map_mod303_data.xml** file is available.

```
   <field name="tax_ids" eval="[(6, False, [ref('l10n_es.account_tax_template_s_iva4b'), ref('l10n_es.account_tax_template_s_iva4s')])]"/>
```

**l10n_es.account_tax_template_s_iva4b** external id is not found in odoo base module.

You can manually change **tax_ids** in xml file or add xml file in comment in **openerp**.py file, after that module will work.

This may help you.

Comment: Your solution fixed the error problem with instalation, but it did not install the module correctly. Below I posted the solution. But thanks anyway :)